ModR/M Historical Notation /0.../7
While learning about x64, I struggled to understand some notations in the intel manual.
Let's look at 0xC7 MOV:



opcode
instruction
Op/Enc
Description




C7 /0 iw
MOV r/m16, imm16
MI
Move imm16 to r/m16.


C7 /0 id
MOV r/m32, imm32
MI
Move imm32 to r/m32.


REX.W + C7 /0 id
MOV r/m64, imm32
MI
Move imm32 sign extended to 64-bits to r/m64.



About the /0../7 it says:

Historically this document only specified the ModR/M.reg field
restrictions with the notation /0 ... /7 and did not specify
restrictions on the ModR/M.mod and ModR/M.r/m fields in the encoding
boxes.

My questions are:

That number after /0 is a restriction code, but which restriction? What does it mean while interpreting an instruction?
If I'm reading bytes like c7c701020304... How to know if I need to ready imm16(0102 or imm32(01020304)? By testing, I know that in this imm32, but I don't understand why. I deduce that it is related to rex+modrm.

{ xxd --ps -r | ndisasm -b64 -; } <<<c7c701020304 
00000000  C7C701020304      mov edi,0x4030201


In other words: Why ndisasm parses that as imm32 instead imm16?


/digit still only restricts the ModRM.reg field. It means, put whatever digit is after the slash, in the reg field of the ModRM byte.
That note is about new Intel AMX instructions, some of which have a different ModRM specification. For example TDPBSSD/TDPBSUD/TDPBUSD/TDPBUU require mod=11 (in other words, they cannot have a memory operand)

And TILELOADD/TILELOADDT1 require mod!=11 and rm=100 (they must have a memory operand, and it must be encoded with SIB)


Oh... "only specified the ModR/M.reg field restrictions with the notation /0 ... /7"... got it... it was hard was to me to interpret that before you said put whatever digit is after the slash, in the reg field of the ModRM byte. Thanks ... But I still can't understand how to interpret the immediate size

@ton: How to read the Intel Opcode notation explains some of the notation, like "ib" meaning 1 immediate byte, iw meaning 2 bytes, etc.

@PeterCordes I now that, but it does not explain my question. "Why ndisasm parses c7c701020304 as imm32 instead imm16?"

I think it means somewhat related to be imm16 at real mode(16bit); and imm32 in other modes; but that table doesn't seems to say anything about that.

@ton: I am sure we must already have an answer on this site, but I haven't found it yet.  But yes, you are correct: 16-bit in a 16-bit mode (real or vm86), 32-bit in other modes.  An operand size prefix (66h) would swap this, making it 32-bit in 16-bit mode and vice versa.  Since you specified -b 64 to ndisasm, it assumes this code will be run in a 64-bit mode, in which case the immediate is indeed 32 bits.  Use -b 16 and you'll see the other option.

@NateEldredge "16-bit in a 16-bit mode (real or vm86)," The D bit can be clear for a 16-bit Protected Mode CS as well, in which case the default operand size is 16 bits too.
